# how to make a rectangle sprite stick to one side in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using a square sprite in Unity for making Android game. I want this rectangle to be always placed at the bottom of the screen. This strip acts as a ground and other objects can fall on it. I want the lower side of this rectangle to stick to the lower side of the screen. How to do it?.
If i try to place it there manually then after I change the screen resolution the placement gets disturbed?
Also the camera is not moving, so I only want to fix the position of this strip with respect to the camera once. (i think so). What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a little more information. Sprites at the lower side of the screen, usually intend to be in the UI. Is this the case? If it is, the way to do it is very different from a normal sprite in the world.
(Since I am not allowed to comment, I will try to answer for both cases, however I am not at a computer capable of running Unity, so I can't really provide a concrete answer (aka: Code))

UI:
Add an Image to your Canvas. Go to your anchor preset (inside the Rect Transform) and set it to the appropriate position. Then, in case you want the image to not be stretched, go to the Image component and Check on the "Maintain Aspect Ratio" (Or something like that) option. Add the sprite to the image and you are all set.

World:
Here, the situation is way more complicated. You first need to get the screen dimensions, then calculate the size of the object according to the aspect ratio, then have some Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint conversion and finally use the LookAt method in the Update() in order to have the sprite face the camera at all times. Or use the UI layer as described above, let's be honest that is probably what you need.

Comment: Yes i need the normal sprite only, not the UI one. I want to have a strip of rectangle at the bottom of the screen which acts as ground. and other things can fall on this strip. So what should i use?

Comment: If that is the case, just make a rather big sprite and let it overflow from the edges and from the bottom. It is the smallest IQ solution, but it will work and it is very light on resources.